# Struggling to grasp posting data to APIs

Tags: python, api

I'm currently looking for some assistance for posing data to an APi.

[image: API information here]

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def discordBotListAPI():
    clientID = client.user.id
    authToken = ''
    guilds = f'{len(client.guilds)}'
    print(guilds)
    users = ''
    r = requests.post(f"https://discordbotlist.com/api/v1/bots/{clientID}/stats", headers={"Authorization":f"{authToken}"}, body={'guilds':f'{guilds}'})
    print(r)
    print(r.url)
```

Here is my attempt, any help would be appriciated - TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has the [answer](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/). The post request body is supplied in the `data` parameter, not the body parameter (which doesn't exist, hence the error). Change your request code to

```
 r = requests.post(
    f"https://discordbotlist.com/api/v1/bots/{clientID}/stats",
    headers={"Authorization":f"{authToken}"}, 
    data={'guilds':f'{guilds}'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ^

Answer (score 1):

replace `body={'guilds':f'{guilds}'` with `data={'guilds':f'{guilds}'`

Comment: Thank you so much ^